# Get Javascript console when emulating WebView app

Tags: android, webview

I'm pretty new to Android Dev, I'm trying to create a WebView based app. I got the basics, I emulate the app directly on my phone and wanted to know if there is a way to get a `Javascript console` like in Chrome PC version.

My device is running Android 4.2.1 API Level 17. I can't emulate app on my computer, it doesn't work.

I've already watched [this topic on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android), but hasn't helped me.

So, what I tried (examples from the Stackoverflow topic) :

- Remote debugging from my device to my computer : I can't cause my device is running Android 4.2.1 and need, at least, Android 4.4+.
- JavaScript Console : I can't access and didn't implemented a browser bar into my WebView app (and don't want to implement one...)
- Original Answer : I put some `console.log('test')` and `console.error('test')` on a `window.onload function` to see if I can find them on the `logcat` and `ADB logs` but I can't find them, even if I put `adb logcat` to search them.

Can someone help me? I really don't know how to get a console, and really need it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The answer you are referring to is for Android Browser app, not for WebView component.

In order to get output from `console.log()` family of functions, you need to set a `WebChromeClient` for your WebView and override `onConsoleMessage()` [(doc)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage(android.webkit.ConsoleMessage)) method, like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        android.util.Log.d("WebView", consoleMessage.message());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Any chances to do the same for ancestors of the regular web client class?

Comment: @mikhail-naganov: Do you know how you could also print arrays `[]`? Currently I'm getting `[object Object],[object Object],...`

Comment: Answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571701/426227)

Comment: its deprecated now